# How do I insert format str and don't remove the matched regular expression in input string in boost::regex_replace() in C++?

Tags: c++, regex, string, boost-regex

I want to put space between punctuations and other words in a sentence. But boost::regex_replace() replaces the punctuation with space, and I want to keep a punctuation in the sentence!
for example in this code the output should be "Hello . hi , "

```
regex e1("[.,]");
std::basic_string<char> str = "Hello.hi,";
std::basic_string<char> fmt = " ";
cout<<regex_replace(str, e1, fmt)<<endl;
```

Can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a replacement variable in your `fmt` string. If I understand the documentation correctly, then in the absence of a flags field, you'll want to use a [Boost-Extended format string](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_35_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/format/boost_format_syntax.html).

In that sub-language, you use `$&` to mean whatever was matched, so you should try defining `fmt` as:

```
std::basic_string<char> fmt = " $& ";
```

That should change each punctuation into that same character, surrounded by spaces.

Comment: and he can replace his std::basic_string<char> by just std::string

Comment: Yes, I'd noticed that, but decided to concentrate on answering the question that was asked.